# Can a SIP call's media address changed mid-call?

Tags: sip, voip, sdp

I am referring to the **c** value of an SDP header. 
[image]

Is it possible that the media stream address changes during a call? And it what scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It may be changed with re-INVITE or UPDATE. Some example scenarios:

- PABX system consisting of multiple machines decides to route media through another media endpoint because of e.g. high server load or some other problem with this machine
- after receiving FAX CNG, CED and/or modem preamble PABX passes the call to fax server
- call is passed to specialized music-on-hold or IVR server

Also, addresses advertised in SIP headers or in SDP quite often are not matching real addresses used for communication because of NAT or misconfiguration - for best results B2BUAs often may ignore them.